# Missing suphp in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, security, ubuntu-server, suphp

I am working on a new LAMP server based on Ubuntu 16.04, but it seems there are no libapache2-mod-suphp package available in the default repositories.
On my formerly Ubuntu server it was available via a simple *apt-get install libapache2-mod-suphp*.

Does anybody have what could happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=738133) suphp is no longer available in the repo. You have to install it manually from [libapache2-mod-suphp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/admin/libapache2-mod-suphp) .

Comment: I see. Thanks. And what is your opinion about libapache2-mod-ruid2? They seem to be interchangeable. Is this correct?

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/libapache2-mod-ruid2 ;   it would be same.